# How to improve a c style function callback system?

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I have a class which I cant change (SuperClass) that has an interface for adding callback which I dont like very much, but I cant make it better. Is it possible to get rid of all the wrapper functions by using some template magic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum EventType
{
    OkButtonPressed = 0,
    CancelButtonPressed,
    KeyPad1ButtonPressed,
    KeyPad2ButtonPressed,
    KeyPad3ButtonPressed,
    KeyPad4ButtonPressed,
    KeyPad5ButtonPressed,
    SomeOtherNonButtonEvent,
    EventType_count
};


// Not sure how the SuperClass is implemented, but from the outside all you can see is 
// the AddCallback(). The class can not be changed. Same applies to the callback typedef

typedef void (*EventCallback)(int argument, void *callbackOwner);
class SuperClass
{
private:
    #define CallbackPair std::pair<EventCallback, void*>
    std::vector<CallbackPair> m_callbackList[EventType_count];

public:
    void AddCallback(EventType eventType, EventCallback function, void * callbackOwner)
    {
        CallbackPair pair(function, callbackOwner);
        m_callbackList[eventType].push_back(pair);
    }

    void TriggerEvent(EventType type)
    {
        int someArguemt = (int)type;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_callbackList[type].size(); i++)
            m_callbackList[type][i].first(someArguemt, m_callbackList[type][i].second);
    }
};

class MyClass
{
public:
    void OnKeypadFunction(int argument){std::cout << "OnKeypadFunction called with " << argument << std::endl;}
    void OnOkFunction(int argument){std::cout << "OnOkFunction called with " << argument << std::endl;}
    void OnCancelFunction(int argument){std::cout << "OnCancelFunction called with " << argument << std::endl;}
};

// Wrapper functions which i would like to remove
static void s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper(int arguemt, void *callbackOwner)
{
    ((MyClass*)callbackOwner)->OnKeypadFunction(arguemt);
}

static void s_OnOkFunctionWrapper(int arguemt, void *callbackOwner)
{
    ((MyClass*)callbackOwner)->OnOkFunction(arguemt);
}

static void s_OnCancelFunctionWrapper(int arguemt, void *callbackOwner)
{
    ((MyClass*)callbackOwner)->OnCancelFunction(arguemt);
}


int main()
{
    SuperClass super;
    MyClass myClass;

    // Register some callbacks
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad1ButtonPressed, s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper, &myClass);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad2ButtonPressed, s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper, &myClass);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad3ButtonPressed, s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper, &myClass);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad4ButtonPressed, s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper, &myClass);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad5ButtonPressed, s_OnKeypadFunctionWrapper, &myClass);
    super.AddCallback(OkButtonPressed, s_OnOkFunctionWrapper, &myClass);

    // How I would like to add the code..
    /*
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad1ButtonPressed, myClass->OnKeypadFunction, NULL);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad2ButtonPressed, myClass->OnKeypadFunction, NULL);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad3ButtonPressed, myClass->OnKeypadFunction, NULL);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad4ButtonPressed, myClass->OnKeypadFunction, NULL);
    super.AddCallback(KeyPad5ButtonPressed, myClass->OnKeypadFunction, NULL);
    super.AddCallback(OkButtonPressed, myClass->s_OnOkFunctionWrapper, NULL);
    */


    // This is called some other place...
    super.TriggerEvent(OkButtonPressed);
    super.TriggerEvent(KeyPad1ButtonPressed);
    super.TriggerEvent(KeyPad5ButtonPressed);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that any amount of "Template Magic" would be "better".  It would only serve to make things more complicated.  What's so bad/difficult about defining a few functions and passing them to another function?

Comment: This is a very simple example. The real code will need a much higher amount of wrapper functions. I agree that other solutions might not be better, but I would at least like to know if its possible to achieve in a more elegant way (even if its harder to read)

Comment: Well regardless you would still need to write *n* number of functions to actually handle the event(s), so I'm not sure what you gain by using templates.  Couldn't you just write one function and switch on the event type?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but that is not very elegant, or cool if you like. I agree with you that other solutions might not be much better (although its a big system, so we are talking about hundred of wrapper functions), but if nothing else I would like to know how to do its as a learning experience.

Comment: Ok, but code doesn't need to be "cool", it needs to be correct and as simple as possible.  Complicating your code just to make it "cool" does not earn you points with your coworkers in the real world.

Comment: true to some extent, but several thousand lines of code that does nothing is also not great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
template <typename T, void (T::*MemberFunction)(int)>
struct CallbackHelper
{
    static void EventHandler(int argument, void *callbackOwner)
    {
        auto myClass = static_cast<T*>(callbackOwner);
        ((myClass)->*(MemberFunction))(argument);
    }
};
```

Which would let you register your handlers like this:

```
super.AddCallback(OkButtonPressed, CallbackHelper<MyClass, &MyClass::OnOkFunction>::EventHandler, &myClass);
```

Comment: Perfect! Looks like its exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Is it possible to wrap templates in a macro?

Comment: MacroCall(MyClass, &MyClass::OnOkFunction) or even better MacroCall(MyClass, OnOkFunction)

Comment: Yes of course, a macro merely performs a substitution. You could write something like this: "#define REGISTER(s,p,f,e) s.AddCallback(e, CallbackHelper<MyClass, &MyClass::f>::EventHandler, p)" which would be called like this: "REGISTER(super, &myClass, OnOkFunction, OkButtonPressed);". This might make the code a little less readable but that might just be down to personal preference.

Comment: True, that makes it very unreadable. I was actually thinking more along the lines of super.AddCallback(OkButtonPressed, MacroCall(MyClass, OnOkFunction), &MyClass), but I see from your answare that the actual template arguments have not been used in the macro, so im guessing that cant be done?

Comment: Never mind, your last reply was more then enough for me to solve it #define TestMacro(a,b) CallbackHelper<a, &a::b>::EventHandler was what i was looking for. Thanks a lot!